# How do I get a list of files from CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket which uses CloudFront signed URLs to control access.

I need to provide a list of files on the server - I have looked through the CF APIs but cannot see anything obvious which does this.

Am I missing something?  Or do I need some kind of workaround?  Is this not supported at all?

Comment: CloudFront is not even aware of the signed URLs until they are presented. If you need to manage an inventory of signed URLs then you can do it in the same app that you use to vend the signed URLs. To list the objects in a bucket, independently of whether or not a signed URL has been created for an object, you can use the S3 APIs. I'm not aware of other options within CloudFront itself.